# AngularJS - Child controller private scope (preventing inheritance)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a case where I need to nest controllers. I do not want the child scope to inherit from the parent scope because I have scope variables with the same names in both controllers. Is there a way to do this?

I am trying to prevent the childController's variable from being updated when the parentController's variable is changed.

```
<div ng-controller="parentController">
     {{myVariable}}
     <div ng-controller="childController">
          {{myVariable}}
     </div>
</div>
```

I am aware that I can change the name of the child controller's scope variable to avoid the inheritance problem completely, but I am looking for an alternative. Is there any known way to do this?

Kind of like isolating the scope of a directive, but isolated or private controller scope.

**Edit:** I have discovered that the child controller will inherit the parent controller scope var value when there is no default value for that var set in the child controller.

Compare: http://jsfiddle.net/4qcqdb6z/ to http://jsfiddle.net/4qcqdb6z/2/

Comment: What about creating a transclude directive with an empty scope? and your childController attached

Comment: That's interesting! I'll take a look into that. Do you mind providing an example of what you have in mind?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? The child div will display the myVariable from the child controller, and the parent div will display the myVariable from the parent controller. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: The problem is that when the parent scope variable is updated it overrides the value in the child scope. (myVariable)

Comment: No, the parent can't override anything in the child scope.

Comment: @runTarm It is happening in my local env. but I see what you're saying. I just tried to sandbox it and it's not occurring in the sandbox: http://jsfiddle.net/4qcqdb6z/

Comment: The only difference between these examples and my local env. is that the parent controller is being set via ng-route

Comment: Ok I found out that @runTarm is correct, but the issue is that the variable is not initially defined in the child controller, and that's when this "overriding" (wrong word) occurs: http://jsfiddle.net/4qcqdb6z/2/

Comment: Yeah, that's normal. BTW, do you still want what you asked, that you expect the variable of child controller to be undefined if not initialzed?

Comment: Well my particular problem is solved by defining those variables in the child controller when it gets executed, but I'm sure it would be of some value in the future to know how to do this.

Comment: The way you did it is fine. You can also consider using the `controller as` syntax (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController), but I dislike it personally.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem while developing my own form. I came here to find no response. So I figured it out myself. So for your code,

```
<div ng-controller="parentController">
     {{myVariable}}
     <div ng-controller="childController">
          {{myVariable}}
     </div>
</div>
```

your child controller should include a scope:{}

```
.controller('childController',  ['$scope', function($scope){
 scope:{}; //this prevents it from inheriting the parent scope variables
}])
```

I know the answer is pretty late but hope those who come across this from now find it helpful

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div ng-controller="parentController as parent">
     {{parent.myVariable}}
     <div ng-controller="childController as child">
          {{child.myVariable}}
     </div>
</div>
```

In the controllers:

```
.controller('childController',  [, function(){
     var vm = this; // You can use now vm like $scope
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to achieve this is to use `Object.defineProperty` in the child controller

```
.controller('childController',  ['$scope', function($scope){
    Object.defineProperty($scope, 'myVariable', { value: 'childControllerValue', writable: true });
}])
```

This will create a variable `myVariable` on the child scope that can be set independently of a variable with the same name on the parent scope.

Angular inheritance works because the parent scope is the prototype of the child scope, so if in your child scope you try to access or assign to `$scope.myVariable` , javascript internally looks back up the prototype chain and actually accesses `$scope.__proto__.myVariable`. By defining a new property directly on the object you mask this inherited property, allowing independent values.

This works when using `{{myVariable}}` in the view. I've tested it with watchers as well, which will watch the variable that is on their scope, not a parent or child version of it. See https://plnkr.co/edit/mXLNGAGc0q8T36DV43aK for some testing.